# Spooling sql to a CSV when data contains commas

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to spool a sql query to a CSV file using a command prompt, however one column of data I'm returning contains comma's in the data and is causing the data to go into the next column. Is there a way to get around this? Ideally, I would like this particular column returned in the middle of query, not at the end.

I'm currently using the following commands:

```
set termout off;
set colsep ',';
set underline off;
set feedback off;
set pagesize 0;
set linesize 1500;
set trimspool on;
```

I know the set colsep ',' command is the issue however, haven't been able to figure out what to replace it with. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Also, right before my sql query, I'm using a select statement to pull the header information. Select 'a, b, c' from dual; Not sure if that makes a difference in the answer or not.

Comment: What type of sql are you using?  Oracle?

Comment: Running the sql through a command job in Control M

Answer (score 7):

Two potential answers. Neither of them perfect. If you have commas in some of the results, but no pipes (`|`), you could switch to a pipe-delimited with

```
set colsep '|'
```

Most software that can read `csv` will do just fine with that format.

If that doesn't work for you, you can realize that to treat commas within a column, you'll need to wrap every data item in quotes:

```
"data 1","data 2","data,with,commas"
```

To do this, each separator will need to be `","` so you can

```
set colsep '","'
```

This will not have quotation marks at the beginning and ending of each line, so you can then wrap every line in quotes with `sed`:

```
sed 's/^[^$]*$/"&"/'
```

Comment: This will not work properly if values contain quotes. Quotes in CSV need to be escaped with double quotes. For example xyz"a" need to be escaped to xyz""a""

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your select query like

```
select REPLACE(column_name, ',',' ') column name from table_name
```

This will replace comma value from your column data with space.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your query that returns the result set by surrounding that column with double-quotes.  Assuming `b` is the culprit:

```
select a
      , '"' || trim(B) || '"' as b
      , c
from your_table;
```

Proper syntax depends on your RDBMS version of course.